# How to highlight a math box in Lyx?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, highlighting

Is there a way to highlight a math box in Lyx?

[image]

Something like this for example?

Comment: You even can highlight the amsmath environments with  package `empheq` (one of the components of `mathtools`).

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure I understand what you are referring to

Comment: I mean that at the level of LaTeX code, you have an `empheq`environment which has a mandatory argument (the name of a maths environment) and optional arguments, among which a key `[box= ... ]`. There's an example at pp. 14-15 of the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard How can I use it with Lyx?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Lyx. Maybe you'll have to add some code by hand to  the code produced by Lyx.

Comment: There is a section in the help file Help > Math that is titled "Colored Boxes". Note that the boxes might not appear colored in LyX, so check the PDF output. Does that help? If you figure out how to do it from the help file, feel free to add an answer and accept it (this is actually encouraged).